# How to use github java API (org.eclipse.egit.github.*) to search for a given commit hash

Tags: java, api, github, github-api, egit

It is possible to receive details regarding a given commit from calling  `github Search API` found in [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-commits) with providing the relevant commit hash, Now I need to get the same response by using  `github java API (org.eclipse.egit.github.*)` which can be found in [here](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core). According to their documentation of the version `2.1.5` found in [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~org.eclipse.egit.github.core), there is no method in `CommitService class` to get commit information by providing only the commit hash . Is there a workaround to reach them? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `CommitService.getCommit(IRepositoryIdProvider, String)` method, just feed in one more argument, the repository where the commit will be searched. For example,

```
GitHubClient client = new GitHubClient(server).setCredentials(login, token);
RepositoryService repoService = new RepositoryService(client);

// If you know which repository to search (you know the owner and repo name)
Repository repository = repoService.getRepository(owner, repoName);

CommitService commitService = new CommitService(client)
Commit commit1 = commitService.getCommit(repository, sha).getCommit();
System.out.println("Author: " + commit1.getAuthor().getName());
System.out.println("Message: " + commit1.getMessage());
System.out.println("URL: " + commit1.getUrl());
```

Or you may just loop through each repository returned from the `RepositoryService.getRepositories()` method, if you don't know which repository to search. For example,

```
List<Repository> repositories = repoService.getRepositories();
Commit commit2 = null;
for (Repository repo : repositories) {
    try {
        commit2 = commitService.getCommit(repo, sha).getCommit();
        System.out.println("Repo: " + repo.getName());
        System.out.println("Author: " + commit2.getAuthor().getName());
        System.out.println("Message: " + commit2.getMessage());
        System.out.println("URL: " + commit2.getUrl());
        break;
    } catch (RequestException re) {
        if (re.getMessage().endsWith("Not Found (404)")) {
            continue;
        } else {
            throw re;
        }
    }
}
```